# How to enable VS code intellisense for absolute path imports in a React app?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio, webpack, create-react-app

So, i recently created a React app and added the absolute imports by updating the jsconfig.json for my project as per the documentation (https://create-react-app.dev/docs/importing-a-component/#absolute-imports). Now I am able to use absolute imports inside my project, but now VS code intellisense seems to be broken, as I don't get autosuggestions for absolute paths. Can anybody point what the reason may be ?

Answer (score 5):

I follow the cra docs and suffer from the same issue, I found the solution which modifies `baseUrl` from `src` to `./src` , hope this can help you!

```
// jsconfig.json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"]
}

// .eslintrc
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "paths": ["src"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot body!!!!  I was getting really upset with this issue ;) and your solution worked like a charm!!!!

Comment: this solution is not working for me :(

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps somebody will find it useful - here is how to handle **path aliases**:

- `jsconfig.json` (the only file we need to add / modify for Vscode to recognize imports):

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"],
      "@c/*": ["./src/components/*"],
      "@h/*": ["./src/helpers/*"],
      "~/*": ["./node_modules/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

- path aliases resolved in `webpack.config.js`:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/'),
    '@c': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/components/'),
    '@h': path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/helpers/'),
    '~': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/')
  }
},
```

Now, when I type, for exaple, `@c/`, Vscode provides autocomplete hints correctly, showing the content of `src/components` folder, or when I "ctrl-click" on the import `@c/Navbar`, the file `src/components/Navbar.js` gets opened, everything works as expected.

And thanks to the author of the previous reply for the hint about `jsconfig.json`.

Comment: this is great, but I'm getting complaints from tsc, anyway to get tsconfig to play nicely with this?

Answer (score 1):

Hi just adding an answer here as I've been struggling with this with the template I am currently using.

Looking at this [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/19342#issuecomment-275052646), the solution was to add a new `jsconfig.json` property:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "es6"
    }
}
```

After adding this option, the intellisense was able to detect my classes' methods and props.